# Not able to download jar from Artifactory repository in gradle project

Tags: maven, gradle, repository, artifactory

I want to connect to the Artifactory repository

https://www.artifactrepository.citigroup.net/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/

and download a jar using build.gradle.

I have 2 repository in my code, which I want to connect: one is local and is where I've download all Gradle related jars and the other is artifactory repository where I want to download TIBCO related jars.
but not able to connect to second repo
This is my build.gradle code

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins-release"

        }

        maven {
            url 'https://www.artifactrepository.citigroup.net/artifactory/maven-cto-dev-3rdpartymanual-local'
        } 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.0.9')
    }

}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'artifactory'
    apply plugin: 'maven'


    group = 'com.citi.recon'

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        distributionUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}/simple/ext-release-local/org/gradle/services/distributions/gradle/1.9/gradle-1.9-bin.zip"
        description = 'Generates gradlew[.bat] scripts'
        gradleVersion = '1.9'
    }

}


artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            maven = true

        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'repo'
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi....WC to SO! Kindly go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. I have edited the question with proper formatting. Also don;t paste code in comments

Comment: Instead of using 2 repositories it is better to aggregate them in a single virtual repository and use this one instead

Comment: Any idea how can we do that in a single virtual repository as both the repository have different url